# Displaying multiple column data in a drop down menu

Tags: list, infopath, lookup-column

I'm using SP2010 unfortunately without SP Designer and only used InfoPath once.

I have 2 lists:

- List A -  Is a list of 'Event Codes' with a 'status' column displaying *Active, Used* or *Reserved* status for each Event Code.
- List B - Has a look up column displaying an Event Code from List A.

When adding a new item to List B and selecting an event code from the drop down box, I want to view all event codes and their allocated status next to each event code.

In effect having data from two columns displaying in the drop down menu.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-gTzHQ8fwVWlJ2dTItTzUxWmQxWjM2MjNITURtdDVNcEtn

Comment: Do you want values to look like this in your dropdown of list B:
Option1: Code1 Active /
Option2: Code2 USed /
Option3: Code3 Reserved /
??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like the drop down menu to display each code, and their individual statuses.
EG:
Code1 - Used
Code2 - Used
Code3 - Active
Code4 - Reserved

Comment: sorry I didnt understood your last comment

Answer (score 1):

1. Create calculated column in SharePoint list.

   ```
   =CONCATENATE(Code," ",Status)
   ```
2. Update secondary data source with adding new calculated column in
   InfoPath form.
3. Set calculated column as data source in dropdown property in InfoPath form.